# How can one type Ctrl+K in the Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I press `Ctrl+Backtick` to open the terminal, then I press `Ctrl+k` and I see in the blue status bar at the bottom:

```
(Ctrl+K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...
```

How can I actually type `Ctrl+k` in that terminal?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a keybinding with the following properties:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+k",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "\u000B" },
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```